# How to delete old image when update ImageField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django to create a stock photo site, I have an ImageField in my model, the problem is that when the user updates the image field, the original image file isn't deleted from the hard disk.

How can I delete the old images after an update?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll have to delete the old image manually.

The absolute path to the image is stored in `your_image_field.path`. So you'd do something like:

```
os.remove(your_image_field.path)
```

But, as a convenience, you can use the associated FieldFile object, which gives easy access to the underlying file, as well as providing a few convenience methods. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile

Comment: Isn't this the default behavior of django ImageField? based on this post: http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/03/02/dont-delete-image-file-when-deleting-django-model-instance/ ?

Comment: The OP was asking about updating a model instance with an ImageField (i.e. user uploads a new image). In that case, the old image is not deleted.

Comment: Note: I'm not sure if it's changed since then or if this is slightly off, but in 1.6 imgfield.name is a relative path. imgfield.file.name has the full path.

Comment: The `name` attribute returns the relative path from project root, I think using `url` attribute is better.

Comment: @AK12 - Even better is `path` - that's an absolute path to the image on the file system. I wonder if maybe the API changed in the past 10.5 years and `name` used to do that. Either way, I updated the answer to suggest using `path` instead.

Answer (score 80):

Use [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup)

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig', # should be placed after your apps

)
```

Comment: This is AMAZING. By the way, as stated in the official doc, you should put `'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig'`, in your INSTALLED_APPS list.

Answer (score 22):

Use this custom save method in your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        this = MyModelName.objects.get(id=self.id)
        if this.MyImageFieldName != self.MyImageFieldName:
            this.MyImageFieldName.delete()
    except: pass
    super(MyModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works for me on my site. This problem was bothering me as well and I didn't want to make a cleanup script instead over good bookkeeping in the first place. Let me know if there are any problems with it.

Comment: You might want to use: 'this.MyImageFieldName.delete(save=False)' cause I've seen the delete() calls recursively the 'save' of the 'MyModelName' Model, beware... and test with a print in the save method

Comment: It's also better to delete the file after the deletion of model it self. If deleting the model fails for any reason you don't want to lose the file.

Answer (score 19):

Before updating the model instance, you can use the delete method of `FileField` object. For example, if the `FileField` or `ImageField` is named as `photo` and your model instance is `profile`, then the following will remove the file from disk

```
profile.photo.delete(False)
```

For more clarification, here is the django doc

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete

Comment: For those who are wondering why `False` parameter is passed. It is to ensure that after deleting the image the model is not saved.

Answer (score 10):

You can define `pre_save` reciever in models:

```
@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=UserAccount)
def delete_file_on_change_extension(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk:
        try:
            old_avatar = UserAccount.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).avatar
        except UserAccount.DoesNotExist:
            return
        else:
            new_avatar = instance.avatar
            if old_avatar and old_avatar.url != new_avatar.url:
                old_avatar.delete(save=False)
```

My avatrs has unique url for each person like "avatars/ceb47779-8833-4719-8711-6f4e5cabb2b2.png". If user upload new image with different extension like jpg, delete_file_on_change_extension reciever remove old image, before save new with url "avatars/ceb47779-8833-4719-8711-6f4e5cabb2b2.jpg" (in this case). If user uploads new image with same extension django overwrite old image on storage (disk), because images paths are the same.
This works fine with AWS S3 django-storage.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an app that deletes orphan files by default: [django-smartfields](https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields). 
It will remove files whenever:

- field value was replaced with a new one (either uploaded or set manually)
- field is cleared through the form (in case that field is not required, of course)
- the model instance itself containing the field is deleted.

It is possible to turn that cleanup feature off using an argument: `ImageField(keep_orphans=True)` on per field basis, or globally in settings `SMARTFIELDS_KEEP_ORPHANS = True`.

```
from django.db import models

from smartfields import fields

class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = fields.ImageField()
    document = fields.FileField()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it will work even if old file is deleted

```
def logo_file(instance, filename):

    try:
        this = business.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        if this.logo is not None:
            path = "%s" % (this.logo)
            os.remove(path)
    finally:
        pass..
```

code will work even without "try .. finally" but it will generate problem if file was accidently deleted.
changed: move model matching inside "try" so it will not throw any error at user signup
Let me know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Completing Chris Lawlor's answer, tried this and works.

```
from YOURAPP.settings import BASE_DIR

try:
    os.remove(BASE_DIR + user.userprofile.avatarURL)
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

The URL has a pattern of `/media/mypicture.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

What I did is saving the path to the old image and if form is valid I would delete the old one.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        old_image = ""
        if request.user.profile.profile_picture:
            old_image = request.user.profile.profile_picture.path
        form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance = profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            if os.path.exists(old_image):
                os.remove(old_image)
        form.save()
```

It is a little messy , but you do not install third parties or anythin