# Delete image in Django

Tags: python, django

I have to delete image from my app. Image has to be deleted from "media" file (directory inside my project) and from database.
Here is my class DeleteImage

```
class DeleteImage(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'layout/delete_photo.html'
    model = Profile
    success_url = reverse_lazy('git_project:add_photo')
```

This is HTML page

```
{% extends 'layout/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% if allprofiles %}
<ul>
{% for profile in allprofiles %}
    <li>
        <img src="/{{ profile.image }}" height="75" />
        <a href="{% url 'git_project:delete_photo' user.profile.id %}">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know if you need models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField()
```

Can anyone help me with this? I saw all similar Questions and Answers but can't figure this issue out... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete old image when update ImageField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878490/how-to-delete-old-image-when-update-imagefield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer that works in my case. :)

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # You have to prepare what you need before delete the model
    storage, path = self.image.storage, self.image.path
    # Delete the model before the file
    super(Profile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
    # Delete the file after the model
    storage.delete(path)
```

It has to be added in Profile class in model.py.

Hope, it will be helpfull! :)