# Custom save method for images/avatars in Django - how to use

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, django-1.11

So, I'm trying to do a little bit of compression of images as well as some other operations. I had a few questions...I have the following save() method for my user class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(storage=SITE_UPLOAD_LOC, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.avatar:
            img = Img.open(BytesIO(self.avatar.read()))

            if img.mode != 'RGB':
                img = img.convert('RGB')

            new_width = 200
            img.thumbnail((new_width, new_width * self.avatar.height / self.avatar.width), Img.ANTIALIAS)
            output = BytesIO()
            img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=70)
            output.seek(0)
            self.avatar= InMemoryUploadedFile(file=output, field_name='ImageField', name="%s.jpg" % self.avatar.name.split('.')[0], content_type='image/jpeg', size=, charset=None)

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I had two questions:

1. Best way for deleting the old avatar file on save, if a previous avatar exists
2. What do I pass into `InMemoryUploadedFile` for the size kwarg? Is this the size of the file? in what unit/(s)?

Comment: The first question is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878490/how-to-delete-old-image-when-update-imagefield/12058684

Ask only one question at a time. If you have two questions, post them separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete old image when update ImageField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878490/how-to-delete-old-image-when-update-imagefield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get file size. Try this:

```
import os

size = os.fstat(output.fileno()).st_size
```

You can read this for how to get file size:
https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stat.html

and for deleting old avtar. According to your code it is foreign key hence before saving you can check if avtar is already exists and so yoy can delete it.
Add this lines code after `output.seek(0)` this line:

```
if self.avtar:
    self.avtar.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the size in bytes.

You can get the byte size of a BytesIO object like this.

```
size = len(output.getvalue())
```