# how to delete previously uploaded image from folder when the user change profile image in python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I have a user profile page from where the user can update its detail and change profile image as well. The uploading of image is working fine . but i want that when the user change its profile image. the previously uploaded image should get deleted from the folder.

I have a `UserProfile` Model which have OneToOneField() associated to `user_auth` table

`models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfileImg')
```

`views.py`

```
   profile_img = request.FILES['profile-upload']

   if profile_img.name.endswith(tuple(ALLOWED_EXTENTIONS)):
      if user.userprofile.profile_img is not None:
         os.remove(user.userprofile.profile_img.name)    <---------this solution is not working
      user.userprofile.profile_img = profile_img
      user.save()
```

[How to delete old image when update ImageField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878490/how-to-delete-old-image-when-update-imagefield)

I tried this solution but it raises an error:

```
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'ProfileImg/model-5.jpg'
```

i have already recheck the folder and the image is still there.
I don't know where i'm getting wrong.
Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a package for that - `django-unused-media` name describes what it does

Visit Documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/django-unused-media/

Comment: ok. but this is not working automatically. I need to manually run the command ```python manage.py cleaup_unsed_media``` to delete unused files

Comment: You can make cronjobs to run the command automatically after a certain period of time. This is the easiest way to do the task