# How to solve "can only concatenate str (not "FieldFile") to str"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the file that I store all the images. I have 2 html, editingclaims and submitclaim. I am storing the images in **models.py** `receipt = models.FileField(upload_to='receipts/%Y/%m/%D')`

Submitclaims allows user to submit an image, while editicingclaims claims allows user to edit the image.

If user submits a new image in the editingclaims.html, it will overwrite existing ones. If there isnt any submitted image, it will display the old image from submitclaims.html

**This is my views.py**

```
# Edit a claim
def editclaims(request,id):
    context = initialize_context(request)
    user = context['user']

    # get original object     
    claims = SaveClaimForm.objects.get(id=id)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # update original object
        claims.name = request.POST['name']
        claims.email = request.POST['email']
        claims.claim = request.POST['claim']
        claims.claimtype = request.POST.get('claimtype')
        claims.description = request.POST['description']


        old_file = claims.receipt
        if os.path.isfile('receipts/%Y/%m/%D'+old_file):
          os.remove('receipts/%Y/%m/%D'+old_file)

        claims.receipt = request.FILES.get('receipt')
        claims.cheque = request.POST.get('Cheque')
        claims.status = request.POST['status']
       
        
        # save it with original `ID`
        claims.save()
      
    return render(request, "Login/editclaims.html", {'claims':claims, 'user':user})
```

Comment: You should use a ModelForm instead of manually dealing with the POST data. As for deleting the old file, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878490/how-to-delete-old-image-when-update-imagefield

Comment: This does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receipt` is a `FileField` when you access returns a file object. Hence you get the error `can only concatenate str (not ”FieldFile“) to str`.

```
 old_file = claims.receipt
 if os.path.isfile('receipts/%Y/%m/%D'+old_file):
     os.remove('receipts/%Y/%m/%D'+old_file)
```

To get the path of the `old_file` use `old_file.path`

```
 old_file_path = claims.receipt.path
 if os.path.isfile('receipts/%Y/%m/%D'+old_file_path):
     os.remove('receipts/%Y/%m/%D'+old_file_path)
```