# How to update FileField data only if a new file has been chosen in django or to delete previous one before upload new one

Tags: python, django

I need your help ... I've got the same question but with another specific class... My needs is to delete previous file before update new one only if field is filled ... If no change regarding file ... 1- When I update with new picture file ... it's ok but it's created a new file with some caracters (moto.jpg > moto_msi2Kup.jpg) ... 2- When I update only with new name (no change on file) ... the image field in database change ... previous it was word/moto.jpg ... after update it changes to moto.jpg (we lost word directory information ...

I hope you understood my needs ... in both case I need to unchange image field if FileField is empty ... If FileField is changed .. Delete previous file and upload new one (still with same name) Below views, models and forms.py and a screenshot too ... Thanks for your help ;)

Here is a video of my issue

[Youtbe Video of my issue](https://youtu.be/FruqGT0RSeQ)

**views.py**

```
def updateWord(request, pk):
    word = Word.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = WordForm(instance=word)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WordForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=word)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.name = request.POST['name']
            # if not form.data['image'] is None:
            if request.FILES.get('image'):
                print("On supprime le fichier")
                word.delete_file()
            document.save()
            message = "Mot ["+request.POST['name'] + "] edité avec succès !"
            messages.success(request, message)
            return redirect('games:word')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'games/createWord.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Word(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='word/')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WordForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ('name', 'level', 'image', 'group')
```

[Click here to see my screenshot for UpdateForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Ouj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use custom save method on your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        this = Word.objects.get(id=self.id)
        if this.image != self.image:
            this.image.delete()
    except: pass
    super(Word, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So your model will look like this:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='word/')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      try:
          this = Word.objects.get(id=self.id)
          if this.image != self.image:
              this.image.delete()
      except: pass
      super(Word, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Duplicate from this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3020045/5380630)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't completly answer my needs :( 
The issue I've is when I modify only name for exemple (not image in ImageField) ... the image field change from word/nom.png to nom.png ...
For delete old image before upload new one it seems to be ok thanks ... but for updating only info without any image choosen ... it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

When you update Data or want to Create Data that time if the previous file was present then the file will be deleted and a new file replaces in its place.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        this = Word.objects.get(id=self.id)
        if this.image != self.image:
            this.image.delete()
    except: 
        pass
    super(Word, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It's working in my case