# Deleting image related to a product from static folder when deleting product. Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    is_digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
 
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
```

I want to delete the related image to this product when product deleted(for example from admin page).
I searched and found out that overriding del or delete functions are not the correct way to do that. Can you please help me.

And I also wonder if it's  even good logic to deleting unecessery files from static folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete old image when update ImageField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878490/how-to-delete-old-image-when-update-imagefield)

Answer (score 1):

Use the django-cleanup app to automatically delete files for FileField, ImageField and subclasses:

1. Install:

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

2. In **settings.py** add this after your apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
)
```

Source: https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped for me. I also used select docerator for specific model.